# Why if $r>0$ contradicts the fact that $d$ is the smallest member of $S$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra. There is the demonstration of the following theorem:

[image]

Which is:

> [image]

> [image]

I am a bit confused: Why if $r>0$ contradicts the fact that $d$ is the smallest member of $S$? I thought about the following: I guess $a(1-sq)+b(-tq)<as +bt$ but when trying to see why this is true, I've run into something with a lot of cases and got confused. Perhaps there is some simpler way?

Comment: $r=a-dq=a-q(as+bt)=a(1-sq)+b(-tq)$ but $r$ was remainder. What are those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where $r > 0,$
it turns out that $r = am + bn$ where $m$ is the integer $(1−sq)$
and $n$ is the integer $-tq.$

So if $r > 0,$ then $r$ is a member of $S$.

But even before you supposed that $r > 0,$ you already had $0 \leq r < d,$
so $r$ is smaller than $d.$

So now if $r > 0,$ we have $r$ and $d$ are both elements of $S$ but $r$ is smaller than $d.$ So $d$ is not the smallest element.

Comment: Damn, it was much easier than what I was thinking. I overlooked that $0 \leq r < d$.